# Extracting part of a file name in python (or bash) from a long list of datasets

Tags: python, bash

I have a list of datasets that I need to extract part of the file names from to put into another program. Obviously I don't want to be copying and pasting all of the file names manually as this would take ages. Is there an easy way to do this using either python or a bash script.

An example of the file names are:

```
mc12_8TeV.156945.MadGraphPythia_AUET2BCTEQ6L1_DGN2N3Slep_110_90-Nominal_Nominal_ISR_ThreeLep.root
mc12_8TeV.156946.MadGraphPythia_AUET2BCTEQ6L1_DGN2N3Slep_112_5_12_5-Nominal_Nominal_ISR_ThreeLep.root
```

I need to extract these parts:

```
156945.MadGraphPythia_AUET2BCTEQ6L1_DGN2N3Slep_110_90
156946.MadGraphPythia_AUET2BCTEQ6L1_DGN2N3Slep_112_5_12_5
```

I need to know how to load the file names into python and then how to extract that part of it.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can use cut or sed, take a look at the man.
In Python you can use method  split() and replace()

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Python way:

```
filename = "mc12_8TeV.156945.MadGraphPythia_AUET2BCTEQ6L1_DGN2N3Slep_110_90-Nominal_Nominal_ISR_ThreeLep.root"

print(filename.replace("mc12_8TeV.", "").replace("-Nominal_Nominal_ISR_ThreeLep.root","")
```

Bash way:

```
echo "mc12_8TeV.156945.MadGraphPythia_AUET2BCTEQ6L1_DGN2N3Slep_110_90-Nominal_Nominal_ISR_ThreeLep.root" | sed "s/mc12_8TeV\.//g" | sed "s/-Nominal_Nominal_ISR_ThreeLep\.root//g"
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: My point was to help to get the answer, suggesting methods or binaries and not simply giving the answer. This takes part of the basic Python knowledge, that's why I gave the a link on the official Python (which will not be invalid before many years).
Next time I will give peace of code...

Comment: Your answer appeared in the low quality review queue. Please show **how** one can do that.